# How to make the UIButton Text dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard

So I have a `UIButton` Inside a stack view. So far the button is dynamic and shrinks in size accordingly. The issue is the text inside does not get smaller depending on the screen size. I am using storyboards and Swift.

[image: The way the button looks on iPhone5]

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I am using auto layout. The buttons decrease in size nicely but not the text inside. It just squished together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get to the titleLabel of the button and `setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`.

here is the objC way

```
[[button titleLabel] setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I uprooted the answer but I don't have enough points for it to show yet.

Comment: No worries -- glad it worked for you -- you should be able to accept the answer. ;)